# Sumproduct with Matched Criteria and Extracted Text

Tags: excel

I posted this Qn at
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1029120-sumporduct-matched-criteria-extracted-text.html?posted=1#post4939092

but nobody was able to answer it.

```
G3=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$E$1=mid(G1,3,4))*($B$2:$E$2=G2)*($B$3:$E$6))
```

Basically using `mid(G1,3,4)` is causing the error. How do I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: You should transcript your question on Stack Overflow. Links break all the time, then one could not tell what your question was, that means nobody could benefit the potential upcoming answers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be mid(G1,1,4) or left(G1,4) if G1 contains 2002CY-Q1 ?

Comment: *How do I solve it?*  I would start by posting the complete question **here**, along with your actual output and desired output. Suggest you read the Help pages for [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Its not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but if your MID expression is supposed to extract and compare the year you have 2 problems:

1) its not extracting the year correctly
2) you are comparing a text value with a numeric value

Try using VALUE(MID(G1,1,4)))